# How to get AWS SES quota usage per templated email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

As I understand from the documentation the SES emails are billed per quantity and per message size. How can I determine the size of each templated email that might or not have an attachment?

I want to have that information to bill our clients. Or should I be using another service for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As you specify - that’s the AWS billing (just keep in mind that there is a difference whether you use EC2 instances or sth different).

About determining a size of the templated email. There are two ways here that I would suggest doing - one easier and given semi-correct outputs and another one harder and giving exact outputs.

1. Easier & semi-correct
   All of your templates create some overhead on the normal email (if it was send without the template), there is 100% chance that the size of the email is going to be less (unless you do some crazy stuff that not all of the fields are used etc, but this is not the case). So in that case, you can store all the information for the template in the database (sadly there is no other choice) and have the size of the template calculated. Then you can easily calculate and estimate the size of your email (by the attachments, additional overhead of the email headers and the content of your email) and afterwards you have semi correct answer (it will always be AT LEAST the size of the mail that is being sent with a bit of overhead but it shouldnt matter a lot).
2. Harder and correct
   You are moving from the normal way of sending emails to use the normal custom “Mime messages”. You also create your own similar template service in your application. Afterwards, you can perform the template conversion by yourself and finally estimate the appropriate and correct size of the email message. The only thing that you woudlnt able to do is if you have set up “open links” in your application and that you should also consider in your application. It would give you a much more acccurate results.
3. What I would do:
   In all your clients you can just calculate how many emails are they sending. I think that you can just take the average of the attachments in the mail (usually the content is really small) and then split the bill based on the calculated averages. You will not have a lot of overhead created from implementing new functionalities in the application and overall everyone should be satisfied with the results (you have all of your bills paid, as well as the customers are paying reasonable amounts of their emails).